# cherrypy and IIS 7

Tags: python, iis, cherrypy

How can I deploy cherrypy along with IIS. I am not able to reach the machine from outside using the IP. If i run using localhost it works. If I give the ip address in the browser from a different machine then IIS7 comes up.

Thanks
Raman

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted more information about your problem but this kinda sounds like a classic configuration issue. If you have CherryPy listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) then it will only answer on that address. You have to configure it to listen on the external IP address if you want it to answer there. [Here is another question that covers how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115773/how-do-i-configure-the-ip-address-with-cherrypy).

It also sounds like you are trying to run CherryPy on a box that also has IIS7 running. If this is the case, and you wish to continue to run both, you will either need to configure CherryPy to use a different port than IIS7 or you will have to configure IIS7 to redirect requests to CherryPy. [Here is a similar question about doing the latter with IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1677828/196626)